# String array run through string until char then save to 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, foreach, char

I have a string array that contains an ID, Path, and File Name. They are all divided by a semicolon and it looks something like this:

> 1.235.554;C:\somewhere\somewhere\this is name of doc.txt;this is name of doc

My code is as follows:

```
//string array already has data
string[] file_final;

//gets height to find array size
int height = file_final.GetLength(0);

//declares 2d array
string[,] table = new string[height, 3];     

for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){ //loops until height is hit
            foreach(char c in file_final[i]) //checks each char in line[i]
            {
                if(c != ';'){ //if not ; then
                   string temp; //I would like to save each char into this string
                   //temp = temp append/insert/+ didnt work
                   // I know data conversion from char to string is an issue                                
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }

     }
```

My desired output would be:

> [0,0] = 1.235.554 (ID)
>
> [0,1] = C:\somewhere\somewhere\this is name of doc.txt (Path)
>
> [0,2] = this is name of doc (File name)

And so on and so forth until we run out of lines in the file to read.

I am having issues with char to string, which I know is two different data types but I thought append would work. Should I save each char until the semi colon in my temp string then add it to the array, clear my string, continue reading the rest of the line, increment my array index then save again until end of line?

Comment: You should just use any library for parsing CSV and store records in list of custom classes. (Does not answer your question at all, but may actually help you achieve your goal if that what you are interested in).

Comment: I'd also use [jagged arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx).

Comment: I would recommend doing a google search on `C# Stackoverflow Convert CSV into DataTable` I've also created as well as posted several simple ways to do this.. also you can create a Class that Mimics the Structure of the 3 fields you want and Split the string into an array there are some many options for this..google the `string.Split()` function

Comment: I can only assume this is a project to learn for loops or some kind of string processing. Otherwise, why store anything... Read a line from the file… split the line on ';' output the results of the split… read next line… etc. No reason to store anything. If there is a reason to store items. A class made up of ID, Path and FileName would be a better and easier approach.

Comment: @JohnG this is not a project to learn loops. I need the table to get the file and output the results on an aspx page.

Comment: @user5468794 Ok i understand. Looking at the problem as you described i question the purpose of the 2 dimensional array since the first dimension as you described will always be empty. This is unless you are planning to do something there later. Also as to reading the file a character at a time to check for ";" characters is well... unusual. A string.Split(';') method would accomplish the same thing in one line of code. Again just my opinion from what you have posted.

Comment: @user5468794 if you make a class of ID, Path and filename... it will make life easier. There will be no need to have a two dimensional array. A single array of the ID objects you created would be an easier way to get the results you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK into storing the data in a `string[][]` instead of a `string[,]`,

Use [System.Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

```
string[][] table = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
                       .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
                       .ToArray();
```

---

If you really need to have the data stored in a multi-dimensional array, you can use this extension method to convert your jagged array into a two-dimensional one:

```
public static TSource[,] To2D<TSource>(this TSource[][] jaggedArray)
{
    int firstDimension = jaggedArray.Length;
    int secondDimension = jaggedArray.GroupBy(row => row.Length).Single().Key;

    TSource[,] result = new TSource[firstDimension, secondDimension];
    for (int i = 0; i < firstDimension; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < secondDimension; ++j)
           result[i, j] = jaggedArray[i][j];

    return result;
}
```

You'd then have the following code:

```
string[,] table = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
                      .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
                      .ToArray()
                      .To2D();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello user5468794 Since i have not explained it very well.. let me give an example.

First create a class of ID Objects...

```
class IDObject
{
  private string id;
  private string path;
  private string fName;
  //public properties
  public string Id
  {
    get { return id; }
    set { id = value; }
  }

  public string Path
  {
    get { return path; }
    set { path = value; }
  }
  public string FName
  {
    get { return fName; }
    set { fName = value; }
  }
  // constructor
  public IDObject(string inID, string inPath, string inFName)
  {
    id = inID;
    path = inPath;
    fName = inFName;
  }
```

Then in Main

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  // since you have an array of the strings...
  List<string> allStrings = getSomeStrings(); // you do not specify how you get these string
  List<IDObject> arrayOfAll_IDObjects = new List<IDObject>();

  foreach (string curString in allStrings)
  {
    string[] splitStringArray = curString.Split(';');
    IDObject curIDObj = new IDObject(splitStringArray[0], splitStringArray[1], splitStringArray[2]);
    arrayOfAll_IDObjects.Add(curIDObj);
  }

  // now you have a single array of the IDObjects
  // you can loop thru it and make your 2 dimensional array if needed

  int row = 0;
  string[,] twoDimArray = new string[arrayOfAll_IDObjects.Count, 3];

  foreach (IDObject curID in arrayOfAll_IDObjects)
  {
    twoDimArray[row, 0] = curID.Id;
    twoDimArray[row, 1] = curID.Path;
    twoDimArray[row, 2] = curID.FName;
    row++;
  }
}

  private List<string> getSomeStrings()
  {
    List<string> allStrings = new List<string>();
    allStrings.Add(@"1.235.554;C:\somewhere\somewhere\this is name of doc.txt;this is name of doc");
    allStrings.Add(@"2.235.554;C:\somewhere\somewhere\this is name of doc.txt;this is name of doc");
    allStrings.Add(@"3.235.554;C:\somewhere\somewhere\this is name of doc.txt;this is name of doc");
    allStrings.Add(@"4.235.554;C:\somewhere\somewhere\this is name of doc.txt;this is name of doc");
    allStrings.Add(@"5.235.554;C:\somewhere\somewhere\this is name of doc.txt;this is name of doc");
    return allStrings;
  }
```

Hope this helps.